# How to clear all commas except for commas in even position in sheet?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I have multiple rows of  string where the string is all wrong. Here is one row an an example of the geometry and output expected:

| id | geometry | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POLYGON (( 106.812271, -6.361551, 106.812111, -6.361339, 106.81205, -6.361177, 106.81206, -6.360905, 106.812055, -6.360582, 106.812065, -6.360218, 106.812293, -6.359295, 106.812593, -6.358644, 106.812436, -6.358406, 106.8121515, -6.3582051, 106.8123, -6.357823, 106.81244, -6.357407, 106.812612, -6.356842, 106.812719, -6.356544, 106.81274, -6.356384, 106.812864, -6.356148, 106.813019, -6.356021, 106.813287, -6.355797, 106.813781, -6.355286, 106.814076, -6.354751, 106.814277, -6.354393, 106.814403, -6.354027, 106.814553, -6.353814, 106.814736, -6.353526, 106.814993, -6.353302, 106.81516, -6.353024, 106.815358, -6.35279, 106.815509, -6.352588, 106.815675, -6.352331, 106.8153007, -6.3521138, 106.8151398, -6.3520137, 106.8149789, -6.3518005, 106.8147643, -6.3516939, 106.8144639, -6.3516245, 106.8141527, -6.3515392, 106.8135734, -6.351342, 106.813171, -6.3512034, 106.8123284, -6.3509219, 106.8122418, -6.3511298, 106.8118164, -6.3521534, 106.8116597, -6.3525047, 106.8111849, -6.3535692, 106.8102245, -6.3554942, 106.8093545, -6.3568947, 106.8085097, -6.3580518, 106.80795, -6.358832, 106.8077793, -6.3590429, 106.807668, -6.359441, 106.807499, -6.360346, 106.8072531, -6.3616378, 106.8071476, -6.3622599, 106.8070637, -6.3626798, 106.8070823, -6.3629367, 106.8071207, -6.3634531, 106.8078269, -6.363831, 106.809448, -6.364124, 106.810574, -6.364198, 106.81066, -6.362993, 106.811175, -6.36277, 106.812087, -6.361703, 106.812271, -6.361551)) | POLYGON (( 106.812271 -6.361551, 106.812111 -6.361339, 106.81205 -6.361177, 106.81206 -6.360905, 106.812055 -6.360582, 106.812065 -6.360218, 106.812293 -6.359295, 106.812593 -6.358644, 106.812436 -6.358406, 106.8121515 -6.3582051, 106.8123 -6.357823, 106.81244 -6.357407, 106.812612 -6.356842, 106.812719 -6.356544, 106.81274 -6.356384, 106.812864 -6.356148, 106.813019 -6.356021, 106.813287 -6.355797, 106.813781 -6.355286, 106.814076 -6.354751, 106.814277 -6.354393, 106.814403 -6.354027, 106.814553 -6.353814, 106.814736 -6.353526, 106.814993 -6.353302, 106.81516 -6.353024, 106.815358 -6.35279, 106.815509 -6.352588, 106.815675, -6.352331, 106.8153007, -6.3521138, 106.8151398 -6.3520137, 106.8149789 -6.3518005, 106.8147643 -6.3516939, 106.8144639 -6.3516245, 106.8141527 -6.3515392, 106.8135734 -6.351342, 106.813171 -6.3512034, 106.8123284 -6.3509219, 106.8122418 -6.3511298, 106.8118164 -6.3521534, 106.8116597 -6.3525047, 106.8111849 -6.3535692, 106.8102245 -6.3554942, 106.8093545 -6.3568947, 106.8085097 -6.3580518, 106.80795 -6.358832, 106.8077793 -6.3590429, 106.807668 -6.359441, 106.807499 -6.360346, 106.8072531 -6.3616378, 106.8071476 -6.3622599, 106.8070637 -6.3626798, 106.8070823 -6.3629367, 106.8071207 -6.3634531, 106.8078269 -6.363831, 106.809448 -6.364124, 106.810574 -6.364198, 106.81066 -6.362993, 106.811175 -6.36277, 106.812087 -6.361703, 106.812271 -6.361551)) |

One example is as follows above. I need to get rid of all odd position commas and only keep the even position commas. So that the geometry can become output.

I tried doing a split(text.",") and concatenate however when the columns is blank it returns xxx,,,, which is not what I had in mind.
Since some have more than 200 commas means that I need to have more than 200 columns, is there a simpler way like using regex?Someone please help.

Comment: `blank it returns xxx,,,,` You need to use `TEXTJOIN()` instead.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: polygon is a string of cordinates in string format. it's a string. Ok will try textjoin()

Comment: Will the second number always be negative `-`?

Comment: An idea using `REGEXREPLACE`  to [replace `,([^,]*,?)` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/Rh1WcY/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, ",")&IF(ISODD(
 SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, ",")))),, ",")),,9^9), ",$", ))
```

[image]

for array:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A3, LAMBDA(x, REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(x, ",")&
 IF(ISODD(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(SPLIT(x, ",")))),, ",")),,9^9), ",$", )))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the second number is always negative, this is simple as  replacing `, -` (comma, space, dash) with  (space).

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,", -"," ")
```

---

If not,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(-??\d+\.?\d*),(\s*-?\d+\.?\d*)","$1$2")
```

- Capture group #1: `(-??\d+\.?\d*)`

  - `-??`  zero or one of literal dash followed by
  - `\d+` one or more `d`igits followed by
  - `.?` zero or one of literal `.`
  - `\d*` zero or more of `d`igits
- literal `,`
- Capture group #2 `(\s*-?\d+\.?\d*)`

  - `\s*` zero or more of `s`pace characters
  - `-?`  zero or one of literal dash followed by
  - `\d+` one or more `d`igits followed by
  - `.?` zero or one of literal `.`
  - `\d*` zero or more of `d`igits

Replace with  capture groups only: `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

An idea to match `,` and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) any [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-commas with an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) comma after:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; ",([^,]*,?)"; "$1")
```

Replace with `$1` what was captured by the *first group* - [See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rh1WcY/2)

[image]